# Equality of subgroups in groups locally finite

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a locally finite group and $X = \{[a,b] ; (\mid a \mid, \mid b \mid)=1, a,b\in G\}.$ Let $K = \left< X \right>.$ Consider $L = \displaystyle{\bigcap_{N \unlhd G} N}$ such that $N \unlhd G$ and $G/N$ is locally nilpotent. Prove that $L = K$.

Remark:
$G$ is locally finite if all its finitely generated subgroups are finite;
$G$ is locally nilpotent if all its finitely generates subgroups are nilpotent;
$[a,b] = a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$ is the commutator of elements $a$ and $b$;
$(\mid a \mid, \mid b \mid)$ is the gcd of the elements $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lemma*. A finite group $G$ is nilpotent if and only if, forall $a,b \in G$, $(|a|,|b|)=1 \Rightarrow [a,b]=1$.
*Proof*. If $G$ is nilpotent, then it is the direct product $P_1 \times \cdots \times P_n$ of its Sylow subgroups. So if $(|a|,|b|)=1$, then $a$ and $b$ are in the direct products of the Sylow subgroups of the primes dividing their orders, which are disjoint, and hence $[a,b]=1$. Conversely, if the condition holds, then Sylow subgroups of distinct primes commute, so $G$ is nilpotent.

Now let $G$ be a locally finite group. The condition in the lemma holds in $G/K$, so $G/K$ is locally nilpotent, and hence $N \le K$. Conversely, for any $N$ such that $G/N$ is locally nilpotent, the condition $(|a|,|b|)=1 \Rightarrow [a,b]=1$ holds in $G/N$, so $K \le N$.